# JavaScript filter through array and only return based on match of one value

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects that all have a phase key and I would like to only return the ones that match a specific phase value and then map several other key/values into the eventual return. Here's what I have so far:

```
phaseToBlocks (toggle, phase) {
  this.phaseBlocks = this.$store.state.addresses.salesRepPhases
  return this.phaseBlocks
    .filter(fiber_phase === phase)
    // .map(({id, phase, name, min_number, max_number}) => ({id: id, phase: fiber_phase, name: name, min_number: min_number, max_number: max_number}))
}
```

This is currently not filtering any out and returning the original array of objects. Here is a snippet of the array of objects:

```
[ { "fiber_phase": "101", "parsed_hash": "1bc7fb114ee10d7cb9cea10693d238b5", "min_number": 400, "max_number": 499, "sales_rep": "164", "id": "abd90d6b-28a8-2be6-d6c1-abd9007aef38", "name": "48TH ST E", "block_minimum": 400, "block_maximum": 498 }, { "fiber_phase": "101", "parsed_hash": "1bc7fb114ee10d7cb9cea10693d238b5", "min_number": 400, "max_number": 499, "sales_rep": "164", "id": "abd90d6b-28a8-2be6-d6c1-abd9007aef38", "name": "48TH ST E", "block_minimum": 401, "block_maximum": 499 }, { "fiber_phase": "103", "parsed_hash": "1e002ef82be950696f9053dc77b621cf", "min_number": 4700, "max_number": 4799, "sales_rep": "164", "id": "a1d58c9c-6ba7-ebc6-8a74-a1d5806e0bcf", "name": "11TH AVE S", "block_minimum": 4700, "block_maximum": 4798 }]
```

Comment: `filter(p => p.phase === phase)` assuming `phaseBlocks` have a `phase` property.

Comment: The key is actually `fiber_phase`. So then it'd be `filter(p => p.fiber_phase === phase)`?

Comment: Yes, if that is the property that should equal `phase`.

Comment: Hmm, still not working. Do I need to map over the array of objects first? Like so:                                                                                                          `return this.phaseBlocks
        .map(({id, fiber_phase, name, min_number, max_number}) => ({id: id, 
            phase: fiber_phase, name: name, min_number: min_number, 
             max_number: 
             max_number}))
        .filter(p => p.fiber_phase === phase)`

Comment: You don't need that unless you actually want to create a new object with that one key name changed. If things are not working, then you're leaving out important parts of the problem.

Comment: It's possible `phase` is numeric and `fiber_phase` is not, which would cause `===` to fail.

Answer (score 1):

`filter()` takes a callback function that checks the condition and does the filtering:

```
return this.phaseBlocks
    .filter(item => item.phase === phase);
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's not clearer for you how `.filter` works, see this:

```
this.phaseBlocks.filter((phaseBlock) => {
   return phaseBlock.fiber_phase === phase;
});
```

`filter` iterates through the array, and `(phaseBlock)` is the element of the array that is currently iterated.

Next, if the item is satisfying a condition (in this case its `fiber_phase` property is equal to `phase`) push that item to a new array created by `filter`.

For more, check the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter